# buffer is being written before old contents are used

Tags: c

It is valid to use memset() to initialize a buffer and then a different call is used to add specific data to it?

Example:

```
        DIR *dirp;
        struct dirent *dp;
        struct dirent *buf;

        dirp = opendir("/dev");
        if( dirp ) {
            buf = (struct dirent *)malloc(offsetof(struct dirent, d_name) + NAME_MAX + 1);
            if (buf == NULL) {
                closedir( dirp );
                return = ENOMEM;
            }
            while( readdir_r(dirp, buf, &dirp) == 0 && dirp ) {
                if( strncmp( dp->d_name, "video", 5 ) == 0 ) {
                    char vidpath[21];
                    memset( vidpath, 0x0, sizeof( vidpath ) );
                    snprintf( vidpath, 20, "/dev/%s", dp->d_name );

                    // Now do an operation that prints the buffer...

                }
            }
            free ( buf );
            closedir( dirp );
        }
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program can be simplified a lot by avoiding dynamic allocation (a `struct dirent` has a small fixed size: the name plus a few ints) The `vidbuf` needs not be longer than PATH_MAX (but if memory is VERY tight, you could use a precomputed value, say 20, and test snprintf() 's return value )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void do_stuff(char * dev);
void do_stuff(char * dev)
{
DIR *dirp;
struct dirent entbuf, *dp;
char vidpath[ PATH_MAX ];

        dirp = opendir(dev);
        if (!dirp ) return;

        while ( !readdir_r(dirp, &entbuf, &dp) ) {
                if ( !dp ) break;
                if ( memcmp( dp->d_name, "video", strlen("video")  ) ) continue;
                snprintf( vidpath,sizeof vidpath, "%s/%s", dev, dp->d_name );

                    // Now do an operation that prints the buffer...
                fprintf(stderr, "Yes: %s\n", vidpath );

            }
        closedir( dirp );
}

int main(void)
{

do_stuff ( "/dev" );

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`memset` initializes the memory to a given value, so it is defintely valid and good practice to make sure there is no unwanted side effect. Since you are using snprintf anyway, it wouldn't be strictly neccessary though, as you are passing in the size-1, so the memset shouldn't be neccessary in the loop.

You should use `sizeof(vidpath)` for snprintf as well though.

```
 snprintf( vidpath, sizeof(vidpath), "/dev/%s", dp->d_name );
```

Answer (score 0):

First note that:

```
char vidpath[21];
memset( vidpath, 0x0, sizeof( vidpath ) );
```

can be written as:

```
char vidpath[21] = {0};
```

But of course it is valid to call `memset` the way you did.

Now as your are calling `snprintf` there is not point of initializing the buffer first.

Also instead of:

```
snprintf( vidpath, 20, "/dev/%s", dp->d_name );
```

you can write

```
snprintf( vidpath, 21, "/dev/%s", dp->d_name );
```

or better

```
snprintf( vidpath, sizeof vidpath, "/dev/%s", dp->d_name );
```

as `snprintf` always writes the null terminator (except if the specified maximum size is `0`).